Making markers of different colours in a line plot using Matplotlib
I have a dataset where i am plotting certain values using a line plot
the points are denoted by circular markers
what i want to do is - have colours of the markers correspond to the nature of the points green for (y>=0) and red for (y<0)
is there an way i can achieve this in a line plot ? is there any other type of plot i could use in matplotlib to achieve it ?
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,5,-1,-2,0]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,3,3])
ax.plot(a, b, marker='o', mfc=['green','green','red','red','green'])
plt.show()

this is what i want to do

You can do it like so
ax.plot(a, b)
ax.scatter(a, b, c=['green' if e >= 0 else 'red' for e in b])


Oh, so plot a normal line and then scatter the points on it later
i had this solution as i used it earlier i was hoping to find some solution by passing a list to .plot itself
but thanks !

I see, I'm not sure if you can do it in a single plot call, but so long as it achieves the desired result it's fine
